# ¿Cómo puedo poner el valor de una id en un input dentro de una columna de datatable?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

Estoy usando en *`server-side-processing datatable`*, y quiero colocar el valor de la `id` en un campo `input` escondido para luego poder capturar dicho valor desde el método POST por PHP. Estoy intentando el siguiente código, pero solo se muestra la escritura de la sintaxis de PHP en el value:

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'modelo', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'marca',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'fecha_marcaje',   'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'id_equipo', 'dt' => 3, 
    'formatter' => function ($d, $row){

      return '<input type="hidden" name="id_equipo" value="<?php $d ?>">
              <center><button class="boton" type="button">Actualizar</button>    
              <button class="boton" type="submit">Eliminar</button></center>';
    })
);
```

Mi valor del `id` se está en `$d`, pero como dije antes, no me muestra el valor sino la pura escritura de la sintaxis dentro del `value`. Quisiera que por favor alguien me pudiese sugerir una posible solución.

Comment: prueba cambiando `value="<?php $d ?>">` por `value="<?php echo $d ?>">`

Comment: o tal ves trata de concatenar el script de php `value=" '<?php echo $d ?>' ">`

Comment: Debes de concatenar pero con puntos. **value="'.$d.'">**, fijese en el las **comillas '** y los **puntos .** estos ultimos se utilizan para concatenar .De todas formas no queda claro el código, trata de explocar mejor la pregunta.

Comment: @Xerif que yo sepa los puntos se utilizan como un +

Comment: @Miyake en php no.  Ejemplo: **echo 'Cadena 1' . "Cadena 2" . $variable;**

Comment: Shimankasu no hace falta que pongas en el titulo "solucionado". Para eso está marcar la respuesta como aceptada. un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es normal que te muestre la sintaxis, estás tratándolo como si fueras a imprimir una variable PHP en código HTML, sin embargo, lo que tienes ahí es un string de PHP que contiene HTML.

O utilizas comillas dobles:

```
return "<input type='hidden' name='id_equipo' value='$d'>
        <center>
            <button class='boton' type='button'>Actualizar</button>    
            <button class='boton' type='submit'>Eliminar</button>
        </center>";
```

O concatenas:

```
return '<input type="hidden" name="id_equipo" value="' . $d . '">
        <center>
            <button class="boton" type="button">Actualizar</button>    
            <button class="boton" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
        </center>';
```

Por cierto, la etiqueta `<center>` se considera [obsoleta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: Muchas gracias, use la concatenación como me lo recomendaste en tu respuesta, y funciono bien, de verdad agradecido por haberme brindado de tu tiempo para ayudarme.

Comment: De nada, me alegro que lo solucionaras :)